# Why is custom domain for Github pages not serving pages for other repositories?

Tags: github, github-pages, custom-domain

Github's [About custom domains and GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-custom-domains-and-github-pages#using-an-apex-domain-for-your-github-pages-site) forum reads,

> After you configure a custom domain for a user or organization site, the custom domain will replace the `<user>.github.io` or `<organization>.github.io` portion of the URL for any project sites owned by the account that do not have a custom domain configured. For example, if the custom domain for your user site is `www.octocat.com`, and you have a project site with no custom domain configured that is published from a repository called `octo-project`, the GitHub Pages site for that repository will be available at `www.octocat.com/octo-project`.

This is exactly what I want. I made a home repository `<user>.github.io` (with a basic static html website) for my custom domain and set the custom domain `xyz.com` and `www.xyz.com` to direct to `<user>.github.io` as explained in [Managing a custom domain for your GitHub Pages site](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site.). Here is how it looks.

[image: Domain Settings]

I also added a file `CNAME` in `xyz-repo` with contents `xyz.com`. Now `www.xyz.com` and `xyz.com` both point to the html in `xyz-rep`, perfect.

Here is the issue though, I have another repository with Github pages that I can access by `<user>.github.io/other-repo-name` but not by `xyz.com/other-repo-name` or `www.xyz.com/other-repo-name`.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you manually created the CNAME file. From the docs at https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site,

> Under "Custom domain", type your custom domain, then click Save. This
>   will create a commit that adds a CNAME file in the root of your
>   publishing source.

I believe Github's system adds the CNAME commit for you: not sure if it will work if you do it? Or maybe there's a specific branch it has to live in? I'd try removing your manually created CNAME file and using the configuration UI.

Comment: I actually deleted the repository and records and did them again, this seems to have fixed it.